# Distribution of last time Brownian motion crosses a line

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

Is the distribution of the last time Brownian motion crosses a line y=a*x known? (Equivalently, the distribution of the last time a Brownian motion with downwards drift hits 0.) It's not hard to give bounds on it, but it would be nice to have an exact distribution if it's known.

Comment: That question discusses the first hitting time, whereas I want the last. Is there an obvious connection that I'm missing?

Comment: A simple description  of that distribution is given in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222705/arcsine-law-for-brownian-motion-with-drift?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is explicitly known, but a bit tedious to write it down. You can find it in section 5.1 (compare also section 4) of

Paavo Salminen. *On the First Hitting Time and the Last Exit Time for a Brownian Motion to/from a Moving Boundary*. Advances in Applied Probability 20/2, 1998. pp. 411-426.

While I do not know about a free version, you might have institutional access to JSTOR, http://www.jstor.org/stable/1427397

Comment: cant it be derived using the analysis done in Billingsley's book convergence of probability measures? he does something very similar for the last time to hit $0$.